# Open url and send header values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to send this request:

```
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
        WebClient client = builder.build();

        client.post().uri(response.getMethod_result().getAcsUrl())
                .header("PaReq", "eJxdUdtu6jAQ/BXEB8R2uCRBiyUKB")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

I want to send a token as header param. But I get error:

But I get error:

`20:21:14.129 [reactor-http-nio-4] WARN  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [id: 0x92efcc15, L:/192.168.1.133:61444 - R:securecode.lisa.mastercard.com/216.119.218.240:443] The connection observed an error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only ' ' and '\t' are allowed after '\n': eJxdUdtu6jAQ/BXEB8R2uCRBiyUKB5UHUERBKn1zzR6I2lxwkob067smSWn7YGlntDuenYXd2SAu
nlCXBiWsMc/VCXvRcdrno0EQ8L6EcLbFi4QPNHmUJlI43HGBdZBmjD6rpJCg9OVhtZHu2HfHAlgL
IUazWkhXeJzzIU02GBIVo8RuOlQ1sBsFOi2TwtTSH3JgHYDSvMtzUWT5hLGqqhyM28lM1Y5OYwbM
tgC7+wlLW+UkeY2Ocr2YVX/fZrf+3OxWU2C2A46qQOlyEfCAez3hTVwxccnEjQcVWy/y33474A4n
uiUgs//MGjCgJYH9ZICiNZjoWgaeTwt1CPCapQlSB2XyXQO7u54/2kx1QWn5h+CS/Vc4F+FoWSxf
94FfvWSH55N6I/Ntk1WMKCvaoJG0AJiVYe0RKZ3bhan6dfkvyA6s2Q==
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpHeaders$HeaderValueConverterAndValidator.validateValueChar(DefaultHttpHeaders.java:492)`

Do you know how I can fix this? After I send the request web page should be returned

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your header value do not contains '\n'.

I guess your code is following:

```
        .header("PaReq", "eJxdUdtu6jAQ/BXEB8R2uCRBiyUKB5UHUERBKn1zzR6I2lxwkob067smSWn7YGlntDuenYXd2SAu\n" +
            "nlCXBiWsMc/VCXvRcdrno0EQ8L6EcLbFi4QPNHmUJlI43HGBdZBmjD6rpJCg9OVhtZHu2HfHAlgL\n" +
            "IUazWkhXeJzzIU02GBIVo8RuOlQ1sBsFOi2TwtTSH3JgHYDSvMtzUWT5hLGqqhyM28lM1Y5OYwbM\n" +
            "tgC7+wlLW+UkeY2Ocr2YVX/fZrf+3OxWU2C2A46qQOlyEfCAez3hTVwxccnEjQcVWy/y33474A4n\n" +
            "uiUgs//MGjCgJYH9ZICiNZjoWgaeTwt1CPCapQlSB2XyXQO7u54/2kx1QWn5h+CS/Vc4F+FoWSxf");
```

So remove all "\n".

I hope it helps.